# Async function inside an async function returns undefined value

Tags: javascript, class, asynchronous

I'm working in a JS class and I can't figure out the reason why `colors.ColorCheck(0).ColorCode` and `colors.ColorCheck(0).Color` return `undefined` values.

As you can see, "0" is passed as an argument of the function `ColorCheck` and is used inside the functions `this.ColorCode` and `this.Color`.

I'm pretty sure I'm missing something in declaring the two functions (`this.ColorCode` and `this.Color`) inside the main function (`ColorCheck`), but I can't see what.

I'm a newbie in JS, so I wouldn't be surprised if the solution seems evident for you guys.

```
class Colors {

    constructor(){}

    async ColorCheck(ID){
        this.ColorCode = (async()=>{
            this.info = await axios.get ('https://.../${ID}.json')
            this.CodeC = this.info.map(t=>t.colorcode)
            return this.CodeC
        })
        this.Color = (async()=>{
            this.info = await axios.get ('https://.../${ID}.json')
            this.C = this.info.map(t=>t.color)
            return this.C
        })
    }
}

const colors = new Colors()
colors.ColorCheck(0).ColorCode
colors.ColorCheck(0).Color
```

Comment: your ColorCheck function doesn't return anything.

Comment: Because `ColorCheck` doesnt return anything. If you want to chain your methods you would need to return `this`. But that would not help here as the function is async `ColorCode` and `Color` arent going to be set by the time the function returns

Comment: I originally wrote an answer, but there are lots of reasons why this code won't work, and I don't want to spend a long time adding every reason to a formal answer. You don't return anything from ColorCheck; you're defining ColorCode and Color as asynchronous functions; your URLs are written incorrectly (`ID` is not actually interpolated); you're attempting to extract a value out of an async function without using await/then; etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `ColorCheck` function is not returning anything, so when calling it as `colors.ColorCheck(0)`, that's returning `undefined`.

I think rather than setting `this.ColorCode` and `this.Color`, with `this` referring to the `Color` instance, what you actually want is to return an object with two keys, `ColorCode` and `Color`, whose values are two [curried](https://blog.bitsrc.io/understanding-currying-in-javascript-ceb2188c339) async functions that will make a `GET` request with the provided `id` when called.

That would probably look something like this:

```js
// Just mocking axios for this example:

const axios = {
  get: (url) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    console.log(`Making a request to ${ url }...`);
    
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve([{
        colorCode: '#F00',
        color: 'red',
      }, {
        colorCode: '#0F0',
        color: 'green',
      }, {
        colorCode: '#00F',
        color: 'blue',
      }]);
    }, 2000);
  }),
};

class Colors {
  constructor() { }
  
  ColorCode(id) {
    return {
      ColorCode: (async () => {
        const info = await axios.get(`https://.../${ id }.json`);
        
        return info.map(t => t.colorCode);
      }),

      Color: (async () => {
        const info = await axios.get(`https://.../${ id }.json`);
        
        return info.map(t => t.color);
      }),
    };
  }
}

const colors = new Colors();
const returnedValue = colors.ColorCode(0);

(async () => {
  console.log((await returnedValue.ColorCode()).join(', '));
  console.log((await returnedValue.Color()).join(', '));
})();
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: none !important;
}
```

You could also move the axios call to the `ColorCode` function (without making it `async`) so that you don't make an additional request every time any of the two returned functions are called:

```js
// Just mocking axios for this example:

const axios = {
  get: (url) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    console.log(`Making a request to ${ url }...`);
    
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve([{
        colorCode: '#F00',
        color: 'red',
      }, {
        colorCode: '#0F0',
        color: 'green',
      }, {
        colorCode: '#00F',
        color: 'blue',
      }]);
    }, 2000);
  }),
};

class Colors {
  constructor() { }
  
  ColorCode(id) {  
    // Note there no `await` here:
    const infoPromise = axios.get(`https://.../${ id }.json`);
    
    return {
      ColorCode: (async () => {
        return (await infoPromise).map(t => t.colorCode);
      }),

      Color: (async () => {
        return (await infoPromise).map(t => t.color);
      }),
    };
  }
}

const colors = new Colors();
const returnedValue = colors.ColorCode(0);

(async () => {
  console.log((await returnedValue.ColorCode()).join(', '));
  console.log((await returnedValue.Color()).join(', '));
})();
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: none !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

welcome! just remember to `await` or `then` the host async function as well

example:

```
async function a() {
  return await http.get(...)
}
a() // undefined (promise awaiting resolve)
await a(); // expected value
a().then(value => console.log(value)) // expected value
```

in case of `function a()`, you can just return the async task itself, which you will have to resolve later anyway:

```
function a() {
  return http.get(...)
}

a() // undefined (promise awaiting resolve)
await a() // expected value
a().then(...) // expected value
```

also:
- you assigned `this.ColorCode` to be a(n async) function, which means you will have to call it in order to get value retuned to it:

```
await Colors.ColorCheck('0'); // Colors.ColorCode and Colors.Color are now being assigned
await Colors.ColorCode(); // this.CodeC is being assigned to the class Colors + returned. which means from now on Colors.CodeC is also accessible
await Colors.Color() // assigns Colors.C a value + returns it. from now on Colors.C is also accessible

note that Colors.info is also assigned and overridden each time you call any of the functions (Colors.ColorCode / Colors.Color)
```

- the `this` keyword is most likely misused: refer to [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) article in MDN. currently your values are stored within the `class Colors` context, instead of probably just storing them in the function's context, using `const`. e.g:

```
const info = await axios...
const c = info.map(...);
return c;
```

Answer (score -1):

You want to use [string literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals), but you are defining as a normal string:

```
this.info = await axios.get ('https://.../${ID}.json');
```

You should change to this:

```
this.info = await axios.get (`https://.../${ID}.json`);
```

Comment: That is not the problem

Comment: @DanPantry well, at least that is A probem.

Comment: I'm assuming he needs to have a callback function on the get call but this lack of template literal syntax is surely a problem as well.